# How do I define variables in Laravel using Routes

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-8

I'm getting errors when trying to put variables in my Laravel code. I know you're supposed to define the variables in the routes,but I'm getting nowhere. I'm trying to build a cms website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
     <div class="row align-items-center mr-5">
    @foreach($abouts as $about)
      <div class="col-lg-6 pl-lg-5 ">
        <h3 class=" font-weight-bold">About Us</h3>
        <p class="text-justify pt-3 mr-5">Test.</p>
        <p class="text-justify pt-3 mr-5">Test.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
 @endforeach
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code that I used in the web.php files

```
Route::get('/about', [App\Http\Controllers\AboutController::class, 'about'])->name('about');
```

This is the code that I used in my AboutController files

```
public function about()
{
    return view('/about');
}
```

Comment: whats in your ```about()``` in ```AboutController```. Please share the code

Comment: I've updated it.

Comment: from where do you get ```$abouts``` data

Comment: answers are almost there

Answer (score 1):

As you want to access `$abouts` variable in your Blade template you should pass it when rendering the `about` template.

It should be like this

```
public function about()
{
    // Here the variable which contain the data 
    $abouts = []; // And pass some data 

    // Here you pass all data for the $about variable to template which is rendered
    return view('/about', compact('abouts'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in the about controller you need to bind to the view the data

```
use App\Models\About;


public function about()
{
    $abouts = About::all();
    return view('/about',compact('abouts'));
}
```

Comment: I'm I supposed to import 'use App\Models\About;'. When I import this, it displays the error 'Class 'Model' not found'. When I import the model, it then tells me try importing class 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model'

Comment: Model was my example of elocuent model, you should use your, in that case now I know is About...About::all(). I updated my answer